# What does this code do if entered in a terminal?

Tags: command-line, apt, sudo, repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:langdalepl/gvfs-mtp
sudo apt-get update
```

Then, launch Software Updater (previously known as Update Manager) and install the available updates. After you update everything restart PC.

If you want to revert back before making any changes:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:langdalepl/gvfs-mtp
```

This was an answer to a question I recieved in the android forums and I don't want to enter it until I've got some idea what I'm doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A PPA, or Personal Package Archive, is a collection of software not included in Ubuntu by default.

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:langdalepl/gvfs-mtp`

This  will  fetch the PPA's key adding the package and enabling your Ubuntu system to verify that the packages in the PPA have not been interfered with since it was built.
The PPA belongs to  user name  `langdalepl` and the PPA is called `gvfs-mtp`

`sudo apt-get update`

This pulls down the latest list of software from each archive Ubuntu knows about including the PPA you just added.

`sudo ppa-purge ppa:langdalepl/gvfs-mtp`

Reverses what you have just done

I would also suggest reading about PPA security  [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/q/35629/71679)

Comment: I would also suggest reading about PPA security http://askubuntu.com/q/35629/71679

Comment: I read the suggested links and now I'm wondering if this ppa is "safe" where can I find experienced user opinions on this ppa.

Comment: In this case it should be safe to use.Many userss have used this PPA. It  has also been recommended by others who read source code.